# Hatzi Kaddish, Kedushah and Barekhu for individual

Tags: kaddish

"Furthermore, in his influential siddur Seder Avodat Yisrael (Rodelheim , 1868, pp. 120-121), Rabbi Yitzhak Baer provides private prayers for those who missed Hatzi Kaddish, Barekhu and Kedushah, but not for the MK."

Source: https://schechter.edu/mourners-kaddish-alternatives/

I saw the variant of Kaddish of the Sorrowful for one in several versions, but I did not meet Hatzi Kaddish, Kedushah and Barekhu. Does anyone have their texts? I did not find Siddur Baer in online format.

And is there a version of the Burial Kaddish in the absence of a minyan?

Comment: Here is the baer siddur https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807&st=&pgnum=139) is Baer's Siddur Avodat Yisrael.

As noted in your question, pages 120-121 contain various midrashic passages an individual can recite in place of *barechu*, *kedushah* or *kaddish*.